# PHP Array as index without array

Tags: php, arrays, types, indices

I have a PHP Script which works quite fine except that I get this error Message

```
Undefined index: Array in [...]/exp.php on line 239
```

On this line there is this code:

```
$out_kostenstelle = $kostenstellen[$nextShift["kostenstelle"]][1].
    "(".$nextShift["kostenstelle"].")";
```

I think the only part where an Array as an Index can occur ist the part where `$nextShift["kostenstelle"]` is the index for `$kostenstellen`.

However when I try to catch this part (it is in a loop with many hundred runs so I can not manually check it) with this code, my script never enters the part inside the `if` clause

```
if(is_array($nextShift["kostenstelle"]))
{
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($nextShift);
    echo "</pre>";
    die();
}
```

This does not make any sense to me and I tried many things. without success.

I think this might be enough of the code where the error could be but just in case here are the structure of `$kostenstellen` and `$nextShift`

Kostenstellen:

```
array(2) {
  [100]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "100"
    [1]=>
    string(11) "Company A"
  }
  [200]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "300"
    [1]=>
    string(12) "Company B"
  }
}
```

and nextShift:

```
array(4) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(2) "168"
  ["start_unix"]=>
  string(10) "1466780000"
  ["end_unix"]=>
  string(10) "1466812400"
  ["kostenstelle"]=>
  string(3) "100"
}
```

Comment: Did you place your `is_array` check just *before* the point of failure?

Comment: just did it and it changed nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way around it: the problem is that the index you're trying to use is itself an array.

When you access an array in php, `$array[$index]`, PHP will try to stringify it if it's not already a string or numeric. Stringifying an array gives the literal `"Array"`; like you have here.

**However**, there's another possibility: that when you run your loop, **the array was stringified already**. It means someplace before, someone casted it to a string.

You could check if with such an if:

```
if(is_array($nextShift["kostenstelle"]) || $nextShift["kostenstelle"] == "Array")
{
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($nextShift);
    echo "</pre>";
    die();
}
```

Comment: FYI, when `array` is compared with anything, `array` is always bigger.

Comment: Ok I see, so I had put Array at some point in my dates and then it did not trigger because The String was Array because of a previous array. I had misunderstood the error. This works, now I can fix the corrupted data. Thank you sir :)